# Buffering points in QGIS, and dissolving to make a single feature for each buffer that touches

Tags: qgis, buffer

I am trying to buffer points then dissolve to a multipart feature for each, but keeping all associated attributes of one of the buffered points (any one).  GDAL gives me the following error with GDAL buffer:

> Warning 1: Value 234000018 of field LNRFTRD of feature 0 not
> successfully written. Possibly due to too larger number with respect
> to field width.

So I tried the native QGIS buffer, then dissolved the buffers; however, it made all buffers a single feature.  I would like the attributes from one of the buffered points associated with each new dissolved feature.

[image: Native QGIS buffer tool]
[image]

Comment: Which ones attributes do you want to keep?

Comment: I would like to keep all the attributes from either one of the points that was buffered in the new dissolved buffer.  I believe I want each dissolved buffer to be a feature.

Comment: Show your GDAL command. The error is probably possible to avoid for the outputformat that you used. And some other format could work without anything special. I would have a try with GeoPackage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Buffer
2. Dissolve
3. Multipart to singleparts
4. Refactor fields to drop all fields (load the fields from template input point layer, then delete all)
5. Join attributes by location to join point data to the buffers (Take attributes from the first matching feature only ...)
   [image]

Comment: This is the answer to my question.  One last question: How do you use refactor in the graphical modeler for this case?

Comment: Nice! In refactor fields "Load fields from template layer" then in "Fields mapping" select all fields and "Delete selected fields"